# How to open android calculator buit-in-application

Tags: android

Thanks to every on to support android development forum.
I want to make a application where when I click a button in my application then open android 
built-in Calculator application.

That means I want to call calculator apk file from my application.
Is it possible?

Advanced thanks to reply

Answer (score 1):

Check [this Tutorial](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2012/06/08/android-open-the-calculator-from-android/)

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.android.calculator2",
               "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
startActivity(i);
```

the above works for HTC only

```
 i.setClassName("com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator",
                   "com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator");
```

the above works for S3

but may not  work for some Phones.

Then see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13662909/4260932)

Answer (score 0):

I have find out the following step:

1. Create an intent with action=MAIN and category=LAUNCHER
2. Get the PackageManager from the current context using context.getPackageManager
3. packageManager.queryIntentActivity(, 0) where intent has category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN or packageManager.resolveActivity(, 0) to get the first activity with main/launcher
4. Get the ActivityInfo you're interested in
5. From the ActivityInfo, get the packageName and name
6. Finally, create another intent with with category=LAUNCHER, action=MAIN, componentName = new ComponentName(packageName, name) and setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
7. Finally, context.startActivity(newIntent)

But I am confused about the packageName and className of buit-in calculator application.Would u known about those information pls reply me ASAP.

Thanks to all