# How to call Android calculator on my app for all phones

Tags: android, android-intent

```
  public static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE ="com.android.calculator2";
  public static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS ="com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
  Intent intent = new Intent();

    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
         intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
         CALCULATOR_PACKAGE,
         CALCULATOR_CLASS));
```

the above works for HTC only

```
  public static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE ="com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator";
  public static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS ="com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator.Calculator";
```

the above works for S3

I need a code that works for all of them. Someone with any clue ?Please give an example code

Comment: try this example http://myandroidsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-open-calculator-from-android.html

Comment: @kumaand This is basically the same...

Comment: @kumaand that only works for HTC but not S3. I have independent codes for both HTC and S3 and both are working. I need one that will work for all of them.

Comment: best way is use PackageManager to get the internal application package name and find `calculator` in all Strings if found then extract main class name or package for starting it.from this way you will support all device or tablets for launching default calculator

Comment: @imran Khan I had the same idea but the implementation is an issue. Please help me with an example. It will give me a head start. Thank you

Comment: @SimonMachaMwas : just wait i will give u some basic code to implement it

Answer (score 39, accepted):

you can try as to Default `calculator` on all android devices:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items =new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
for (PackageInfo pi : packs) {
if( pi.packageName.toString().toLowerCase().contains("calcul")){
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
    map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
    items.add(map);
 }
}
```

and now you can launch calculator application as:

```
if(items.size()>=1){
String packageName = (String) items.get(0).get("packageName");
Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
if (i != null)
  startActivity(i);
} 
else{
      // Application not found
   }
```

And for **Api >= 15** ,You can use

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: i'm sure this code will work on all devices for launching calculator application

Comment: let me try it will tell u in a min

Comment: Thank you big !! it worked man Thanks alot it is working for all phones

Comment: I have tested on both HTC ONE X and Sam Sung S3 devices. You really saved me alot !! :)

Comment: On my device, launched the "Solution Calculator" chemistry application.

Comment: I just added a foreach loop after your check on `items.size()` to check if the appName `startsWith("calc")`. If so, I set the package name equal to that element of `items` instead of `items.get(0)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to check if the default calculator package name(com.android.calculator2) is available with this:

```
try{
     ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager()
                             .getApplicationInfo("com.android.calculator2", 0 );

    } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
     //application doesn't exist
}
```

Samsung uses a lot of apps preinstalled with TouchWiz which aren't available in stock Android. Therefore if you get an Exception in the above you can check if Samsung's calculator is available.
Btw I *think* com.android.calculator2 is not HTC specific.

Comment: @Ahmed everything is ok with HTC One X now how do i get both HTC and  S3 working. am not getting any exception. Do you have any idea of how to go about it. How do i get the package and the class of the calculator

Comment: Samsung's calculator on my phone is com.sec.android.app.popupcalculator .

Answer (score 0):

Well this is a **Modified Answer of @ρяσѕρєя K**
becouse it works fine in samsung mobiles and only packages have "calc" 
but not all mobiles like HTC AND LENOVO ETC

**And for Api >= 15 ,You can use BUT !!!**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

THIS MAY CAN CAUSE ERROR LIKE THIS

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle
>   Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN
>   cat=[android.intent.category.APP_CALCULATOR] flg=0x10000000 }

**SO LETS TAKE A LOOK AT THIS**

**LOAD all apps to Array**

```
    // Declare universal if you want Access any where from scope


ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>> items;
    PackageManager pm ;    
List<PackageInfo> packs;

    // initialise From Oncreate if you want
    items =new  ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>(); 
    pm = getPackageManager();
    packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);  
        for (PackageInfo pi : packs)
 {
            HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            map.put("appName", pi.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm));
            map.put("packageName", pi.packageName);
            items.add(map); 
 }
```

**THIS IS TRICK PART**
We are Traversing through all Apps to get App Named or Matches "Calculator"

```
public void opencalculator(){
  int d=0;
  if(items.size()>=1){
  int j=0;
 for(j=0;j<items.size();j++){
 String AppName = (String) items.get(j).get("appName");
// Log.w("Name",""+AppName);
    if(AppName.matches("Calculator"))
                     {
                            d=j;
                            break;
                     }
                    }
                    String packageName = (String) items.get(d).get("packageName");

                    Intent i = pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
                    if (i != null){
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"STARTING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        startActivity(i);}
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"SORRY I CANT OPEN CALCULATOR :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }


                else{
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"SORRY I CANT START CALCULATOR :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
}
```

CALL OPENCALCULATOR

```
opencalculator();
```