# How to make layout(elements) matching all screen and remove space between buttons

Tags: android

Hello I have developing calculator app where app should be on all screen and buttons like in the 2 image and i have stopped there and i have tried all methods please help me to make it.Does  anybody know how tp make style like in second image or any tutorials about it because I am newbie in android developing. I have trie with buttons 4 5 6 and the resul is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/functionPad"
android:background="#043136"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".12" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="40sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".12" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClearMemory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonClearMemory"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonAddToMemory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonAddToMemory"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubtractFromMemory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonSubtractFromMemory"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonRecallMemory"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonRecallMemory"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/row3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".12" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonClear"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonToggleSign"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonToggleSign"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonDivide"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonMultiply"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".12" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button7"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button8"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button9"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonSubtract"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/row5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".12" >

    <Button
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="#2B393B"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dip"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button4"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-8dip"
        android:background="#262626"
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button5"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_marginRight="-5dip"
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/button6"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonAdd"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/row6"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".24"
    android:baselineAligned="false" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".75"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:textSize="25sp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:text="@string/button1"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:text="@string/button2"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:text="@string/button3"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".50" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button0"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".66"
                android:text="@string/button0"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonDecimalPoint"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".34"
                android:text="@string/buttonDecimalPoint"
                android:textSize="25sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".25"
        android:text="@string/buttonEquals"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Preferred!Screen from Calcu app![][1]]
[image: I Have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's better to you make use of the default calculator of all devices as @ρяσѕρєя-k explained here: [How to call android calculator on my app for all phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662506/how-to-call-android-calculator-on-my-app-for-all-phones)