# How to Open default calculator

Tags: android

I am using below code for displaying default calculator. But i am getting activityNotFound exception.

```
 public static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE ="com.android.calculator2";
public static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS ="com.android.calculator2.Calculator";

 Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(
                        CALCULATOR_PACKAGE,
                        CALCULATOR_CLASS));

                try {
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {
                    // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662506/how-to-call-android-calculator-on-my-app-for-all-phones

Comment: There are ~10,000 Android device models. None have to have a calculator. Those that do can have whatever calculator app that they want. None have to have `com.android.calculator2`, and `com.android.calculator2.Calculator` does not have to be an exported activity, let alone a launcher activity.

Comment: @AmjadOmari Thanks for your help. it works for me.

Comment: @ModularSynth check the answer which shared by Amjad . that solved my issue

Comment: @ModularSynth Yes. But we are developing an app where user don't need to search calculator in app they can directly click on calculator button and can calculation. it will save our user timeing

Answer (score 0):

This intent should get your job done

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR);
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Note that this does not match what [the JavaDocs say for that category](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#CATEGORY_APP_CALCULATOR).