# Android mismatch in Calculator package (emulator vs. real device)

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have a physical Pixel 2 XL device. The Calculator app on it is `com.google.android.calculator`. However, when I use a virtual Pixel 2 XL device (created via Andrdoid Studio's virtual device manager) the Calculator on it is `com.android.calculator2`.

Questions:

a/ What's the reason for this discrepancy?

b/ How can I create a virtual device with a Calculator app that is identical to the one on physical devices?

Virtual device:

```
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 
8.1.0
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
27
$ adb shell getprop ro.product.model
Android SDK built for x86
$ adb shell pm list packages calc
package:com.android.calculator2
```

Physical device:

```
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release 
8.1.0
$ adb shell getprop ro.build.version.sdk 
27
$ adb shell getprop ro.product.model
Pixel 2 XL
$ adb shell pm list packages calc
package:com.google.android.calculator
```

Comment: Check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662506/how-to-call-android-calculator-on-my-app-for-all-phones

Comment: I think is the app is installed on `Virtual` is not really the same of your device because the copyright of google. I make rom on phone my phone and at the start we can included this but I don't exactly when google don't authorize this the user need to install manually the apps.